# The new class in my second package in the same project doesn't run in Netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans, package, project

I've made a new package in the same project, and I can't seem to run the class in the new package. When I click on Run while in the new class, it doesn't run. Any ideas, on how to run this new class? I'm new to Netbeans and Java. Files look like this:

- JavaApplication1 (project name)

  - Source Packages

    - javaapplication1

      - Test.java
    - javaapplication2

      - NewClass.java

Comment: packages don't "run". does your NewClass have a main method?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes it does! But the main from Test.java runs when I click run.

Comment: And where do you click?

Comment: @Stultuske I click the Run Project Icon in the toolbar.

Comment: @Stultuske I figured out the 'Run File' option :) It runs now :)

Comment: The reason for that is, that each project has one single class configured as it's entry point. Just like a jar: in the manifest.mf there's only a single class set as the class containing the main method, so that's the main method that 'll be used. You could change that, but if you have several main methods in the same project between which you want to switch, 'Run File' is indeed the better option.

Comment: Thanks that explains alot :) @Stultuske

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `NewClass` have `main` metod? If yes you have 2 options.

1. You can select main class for procject by rigth clickong on project and selecting `Propperties`. And then in `Run` node select main class as shown in image blow.
   [image]

2.) You can run specific file from ide by rigth clickin on file and select `run file` as shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second package is not considered as source for building you need to change project settings so that second package also gets built